# Como passar um parâmetro do tipo enum junto com o Model para uma PartialView - Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Estou tendo dificuldades para passar uma parâmetro do tipo enum para uma PartialView usando ViewData. Está dando erro de conversão (na PartialView), pois o  tipo recebido parece ser string ou outro tipo e fica diferente do enum. Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Chamada da PartialView:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Pessoa/_PessoaGenerico.cshtml", Model, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData){ { "pessoaTipo", PessoaTipo.Filial } })
```

Recebimento do parametro na PartialView:

```
@model Retaguarda.Application.ViewModels.Pessoa.PessoaGenericoViewModel
@{
    PessoaTipo pessoaTipoRecebido = this.ViewData.ContainsKey("pessoaTipo") ? this.ViewData["pessoaTipo"] : PessoaTipo.Filial; //Caso não receba o valor do parametro será setado para Filial. 
}
```

Enum:

```
public enum PessoaTipo
{
    [Description("PESSOA")]
    Pessoa = 1,
    [Description("FILIAL")]
    Filial = 2,
    [Description("USUÁRIO")]
    usuario = 3,
    [Description("CLIENTE")]
    Cliente = 4,
    [Description("FORNECEDOR")]
    Fornecedor = 5,
    [Description("FUNCIONARIO")]
    Funcionario = 6
}
```

Comment: Me parece necessário ser feito o cast, algo assim `PessoaTipo pessoaTipoRecebido = this.ViewData.ContainsKey("pessoaTipo") ? (Models.PessoaTipo)this.ViewData["pessoaTipo"] : PessoaTipo.Filial;` Onde Models é o `namespace`.

Comment: Funcionou!!! Obrigado @Barbetta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É necessário que seja feito o `cast` do `ViewData` pois ele não sabe que dentro dele contém um `PessoaTipo`.

Sua linha de código deveria ser assim:

`PessoaTipo pessoaTipoRecebido = this.ViewData.ContainsKey("pessoaTipo") ? (Models.PessoaTipo)this.ViewData["pessoaTipo"] : PessoaTipo.Filial;`